# Hidden textarea momentarily taking focus

Tags: orbeon

I'm having an issue with hidden (relevant='false()') textarea controls. When tabbing across the hidden control (ie hitting tab in the previous control) the focus disappears for a moment then reappears in the same control. Tabbing twice quickly will get to the next control successfully.

To recreate, create a 3 control form: input, textarea and input. Make the textarea visibility=false(). Test the form and tab away from the first control.

Using Orbeon 4.3 PE. Doesn't occur with hidden input or output controls.

Anyone seen this before?

Regards

Jez

Comment: Thanks for the question, as this behavior was due to a bug we were not aware of, and this gave us a chance to fix it just before the 4.4 release (also see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug ([issue 1387](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1387)), which is fixed as of Orbeon Forms 4.4.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Looking forward to 4.4.